# How to avoid validation layer errors about unused vertex inputs?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I get a lot of errors like:

```
The Pipeline State Object (0x51) expects that this Command Buffer's vertex binding Index 10 should be set via vkCmdBindVertexBuffers. This is because VkVertexInputBindingDescription struct at index 10 of pVertexBindingDescriptions has a binding value of 10.'
```

The reason is that I have a shader where certain vertex inputs are used depending on the values of some specialization constant, e.g.:

```
layout(constant_id = 0) const bool flag = false;
layout(location    = 0) in vec3 input;

void main() {
  if (flag) {
    f(input);
  } else {
    // ignore input
  }
}
```

Everything works properly nonetheless, since I'm not actually using `input`.

What's the right approach to ignore/silence these errors? Is it OK to just bind a dummy empty buffer to those bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valid usage for all of the `vkCmdDraw` commands says:

> All vertex input bindings accessed via vertex input variables declared in the vertex shader entry point’s interface must have valid buffers bound

This is very similar to the rule for other resource bindings which are handled via descriptors:

> Descriptors in each bound descriptor set, specified via vkCmdBindDescriptorSets, must be valid if they are statically used by the bound VkPipeline object, specified via vkCmdBindPipeline

The spec is consistent about *not* requiring dead code elimination to be performed based on specialization constants. Without DCE, the call to `f(input)` is still present in the shader, even if it won't ever be executed. So the `input` variable is still statically used / declared in the interface, and the above valid usage applies.

So you do have to have a buffer bound. However, it can be very small since you never actually read from it, and you don't have to fill it with data .. it can contain random uninitialized garbage (if the validation layers complain about that, it should only be as a warning, not as an error).

Comment: I should say, as long as you set the usages appropriately when creating the buffer, you could totally point the vertex buffer binding at some other buffer (like a uniform buffer) that you're using for something else. You don't need to have a completely unused buffer for this.

Comment: *Without DCE, the call to f(input) is still present in the shader, even if it won't ever be executed.*
But is the condition `if (flag)` evaluated every time or is it optimized out due to the specialization? (I would expect the latter)

Comment: The driver's shader compiler very likely optimizes out the conditional and the call to f(input), so you're probably not losing performance by doing it this way. But that optimization isn't guaranteed, so the spec has to be conservative and say you must bind something to input. And the validation layers just check against what the spec says; they don't have a way of knowing whether the driver needs the buffer bound or not. (And even if they did know, because *some* driver might not do that, they would still let you know you have a portability bug.)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, my solution is create a dummy buffer, bind memory and copy some data to it. This silences the errors from validation layer.

Binding the memory and copying some data is necessary, otherwise I get a warning: `Cannot read invalid region of memory allocation XXX for bound Buffer object XXX, please fill the memory before using.`.

I would like to know if there's a cleaner solution, though.